# PHP: How to integrate the update of my nickname without having to sign out and sign in to see the new nickname?

Tags: php

I'm working on a registration and log in form with PHP and I have a problem. Currently, everything works perfectly, but I have just a little problem. When the user is connected, in his account, I added the ability to change his nickname. My code works, but I've a problem. When I change my nickname, the nickname is updated in the database, but not in my header:

http://prntscr.com/8o2ipa

Code:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href=".">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="visitor-links">
            <?php if(isset($_SESSION["auth"])): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="account.php" class="account">Welcome, <?= $_SESSION["auth"] -> nickname; ?></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="sign-out.php" class="sign-out button primary">Sign Out</a>
            </li>
            <?php else: ?>
            <li>
                <a href="sign-in.php" class="sign-in">Sign In</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="sign-up.php" class="sign-up button primary">Sign Up</a>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code for the nickname update:

```
if(!empty($_POST["nickname"]))
{
        $user_id = $_SESSION["auth"] -> id;
        $req = $pdo -> prepare("UPDATE users SET nickname = ?") -> execute([$_POST["nickname"]]);
        $_SESSION["flash"]["success"] = "Your nickname has been updated.";
}
```

If I put a new nickname in the nickname field, the old nickname is still in the header: http://prntscr.com/8o2mfx

So for I can see the new nickname, I have to log out from the session and to log in. How could I make it instantaneous?

Sorry for my English, I'm French.

Comment: just do redirect after post something like header("redirect_page_location").

Comment: your session array is still kept in memory/cache. Destroying/unsetting the session will/should fix that.

Comment: Yes, but if I do a session destroy, I need to log in and I don't want that. I want that the user is still connected after the changes

Comment: You have `Welcome, <?= $_SESSION["auth"] -> nickname; ?>`, but where after changing the nickname you're changing the `session['auth']` value?

Comment: To log in, I use this for the nickname: `$req -> execute(["nickname" => $_POST["nickname"]]);`

Comment: Yeah, but if are already loged in when changing the nickname, you have to update the session value, right? I mean, if you're reading session value, you are setting it first somewhere.

Comment: Yes, but how can I do that without disconnect the user?

Comment: Yes, but it must be something dynamic, not static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you're reading the session value `nickname` from `auth`, but it's always the same, you never change its value, even though the database value might be different.

What you have to do is change it, then (added last line):

```
if(!empty($_POST["nickname"]))
{
    $user_id = $_SESSION["auth"] -> id;
    $req = $pdo -> prepare("UPDATE users SET nickname = ?") -> execute([$_POST["nickname"]]);
    $_SESSION["flash"]["success"] = "Your nickname has been updated.";
    // added this line \/
    $_SESSION["auth"] -> nickname = $_POST["nickname"]; 
}
```

so that next time you read session value `Welcome, <?= $_SESSION["auth"] -> nickname;` you have the new one.

*Just a plus. You should create some verifications in your code, such as check if any error ocurred during the update, that way you don't show a nickname to the user that is different from the DB.*

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works. For the errors, yes, I know that. ;) I just posted the nickname code.